# How to pass optional python arguments to sub-functions with optional arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x

Given a simple Python function with an optional argument, like:

```
def wait(seconds=3):
    time.sleep(seconds)
```

How do I create a function that calls this and passes on an optional argument? For example, this does NOT work:

```
def do_and_wait(message, seconds=None):
    print(message)
    wait(seconds)
```

**Note**: I want to be able to call `wait` from other functions with the optional `seconds` argument without having to know and copy the current default `seconds` value in the underlying `wait` function to every other function which calls it.

As above, if I call it with the optional argument, like `do_and_wait(2)` then it works, but trying to rely on `wait`'s default, e.g. calling it like `do_and_wait()` causes a TypeError because inside `wait` seconds == None.

Is there a simple and clean way to make this work? I know I can abuse kwargs like this:

```
def do_and_wait(message, **kwargs):
    print(message)
    wait(**kwargs)
```

But that seems unclear to the reader and user of this function since there is no useful name on the argument.

Note: This is a stupidly simplified example.

Comment: In your example, `seconds` is not optional, but rather it has a default value that will be used if the argument isn't provided. Since you call `wait` from `do_and_wait`, you're always overriding that default with `None` - you could simply change the default value for `seconds` in `do_and_wait` to `3`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand you've simplified your question, but I think you mean how one can call a function with optional arguments that could be None. Does the following work for you?

```
import time

def func1(mess, sec):
  if sec != None:
    time.sleep(sec)
  print(mess)


func1('success', sec=None)
```

Comment: thanks - your code helped me come up with the way to do it, below

Comment: fyi, use `if sec is not None` instead of the `!=` operator

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you've quite explained your problem completely because I don't expect an answer should be this simple, but I would just use the same default value (and data type) in do_and_wait() as wait() uses, like so:

```
def do_and_wait(message, seconds=3):
    print(message)
    wait(seconds)
```

Answer (score 0):

After thinking a bit more, I came up with something like this; Han's answer suggested this and reminded me that I think PEP even suggests it somewhere. This especially avoids having to know and copy the default value into any function that calls `wait` and wants to support a variable value for `seconds`.

```
def wait(seconds=None):
    time.sleep(seconds if seconds is not None else 3)

def do_and_wait(message, seconds=None):
    print(message)
    wait(seconds)

def something_else(callable, seconds=None):
    callable()
    wait(seconds)
```